# Show history of a single file across all branches

Tags: git, git-log

How can I show the complete history of a single file in Git? When I use `git log <filename>` or `gitk <filename>`, I only get merges. I want to see the commits from the merged branches that affect the file. I've tried `--follow` and other flags and can't find a way.

Comment: Does `git log --all --full-history -- path/to/file` do it for you?

Comment: No, it just shows even more merges...

Comment: mmm. add `--no-merges` to see if there's anything valuable hiding in the chaff.

Comment: I found out the problem! The merge was actually a subtree merge, so the history was showing the add only. Detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918244/git-subtree-without-squash-view-log

Answer (score 6):

This will show all versions of the file (merges or not):

```
gitk --all <filename>
```

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR summary: `--all`

First, let me tackle one general item that applies to many git commands.

`git log` looks at the revision(s) you specify, using `git rev-list` to handle them.  The reason you normally see many commits is that `git rev-list` "walks history", unless told not to:

```
$ git rev-list --no-walk HEAD
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f
$ git rev-list HEAD
d1574b852963482d4b482992ad6343691082412f
b9491ea160d12ddfd69a9ddc79ebd264cda20679
676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094
[snip]
```

However, the revisions visited by `git rev-list` *start* from the point(s) you specify (with default = `HEAD`).  So any revisions that are *not* already part of the point(s) you specified, or its history, are omitted:

```
        C - D           <-- branchA
      /
A - B - E - F - G       <-- branchB
      \
        H - I - J - M   <-- HEAD=branchC
          \       /
            K - L
```

In this diagram I've put in three branch names, and shown that `HEAD` is `branchC`.  Each single letter represents a commit (an SHA-1).  Any commit's parents are those to the left of it, either directly left or moving up or down along the parent-commit links that go between commits.

At this point, `git log` will show you commits `M`, `L`, `K`, `J`, `I`, `H`, `B`, and `A`, because `git log` (and `git rev-list`) will start at `HEAD` and walk backwards.  (The precise order of these commits depends on additional arguments.)

On the other hand, `git log branchB` will show you commits `G`, `F`, `E`, `B`, and `A`, because starting at commit `G` and walking backwards selects those commits (and no others).  Similarly, `git log branchA` starts with `D` and walks back to `A`.

If you ask `git rev-list` to look at `--all`, it will start at *all* references (all branches, all tags, all remote-branches, and all other refs in the `refs/` namespace) and walk backwards.  In this case, all branches alone suffices to select every commit.  In repositories with tags, `--branches` might get you less than `--all`, since there might be some line(s) that are tagged but not marked with a branch.  See the (rather overwhelming) [`git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) to see all available options here.

---

Adding a file name to `git log` makes it skip the *printing* of some (many or most) of the commits it visits, through what is described in the documentation as ["History Simplification"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_history_simplification).  That is, `git log` first *selects* all the commits selected by your `git rev-list` arguments, but then it only *shows* a smaller number.

Adding `--follow` makes `git log` attempt to notice cases where a file is renamed across a particular commit, and in those cases, switch selected revisions to those with the previous name once it transitions across such commits in its history-walk.  In other words, it tries to adjust the history simplification to correct for name changes.  This rename discovery is performed dynamically (re-tested for every pair of commits).  It works only when stepping backwards—the code is just not there for handling other commit-orders.

When using `git diff`, you have more control over what is recognized as a rename; with `git log`'s `--follow`, you're stuck with the compiled-in default of a 50% match.

Comment: I tried using `git log --all <filename>` and it still only shows merges.

Comment: It's possible that the file is only modified in those merges.  That would be *rare*, to be sure, but it is possible.  (It's not entirely clear what "modified" should mean for a merge, since a merge has multiple parents; `git show` shows combined diffs for merges by default, which show only files modified in both parents.  I'm not sure off-hand whether `git log` does the same.)