# GitHub wiki IS the project, how to get all the stats and graphs?

Tags: git, github, markdown, gollum-wiki

I'm working on an open-source wiki using the GitHub's built-in gollum on the wiki tab of the project. So the wiki is itself the project. But though I've done tons of commits on the wiki repository, in the main project repository (the one with the graphs), it doesn't show that activity. Should I just get over that? Or is there a way to mirror the two repositories so that I don't have to explicitly tell people to go to the wiki when they go looking for it and find just one readme file?

I've checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941688/how-to-integrate-a-github-wiki-into-the-main-project) about using submodules, but I'm not sure if that will get me what I want on the graphs, in terms of commit history, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I chose was simply to use the wiki to edit and host, and periodically pull from that repository into the main code repository just for the sake of graphing and stats. I specify in the readme file that people should go to the wiki since it's intended to be used with Gollum's sidebar/footer features.

In the future I'd like to figure out how to push from the main code into the gh-pages branch for use with GitHub Pages, but so far I haven't been able to get it working. (The layouts available with the single-page edit feature don't appear to be available for use for manual pushes.)

Comment: I'd like to do this too. Kinda sucks. Open an issue on gollum?