# Add and commit changes to all git's branches with one command

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-worktree

I have a git repo in my computer and one of the directories inside this repo is a git worktree that holds the html build of the docs. So the tree goes something like this

```
. # <--- main branches here!
├── docs
│   └── _build
│       ├── doctrees
│       ├── html # <--- gh-pages branch here!
│       │   ├── _modules
│       │   ├── _sources
│       │   └── _static
│       └── latex
├── examples
└── mypackage
    ├── subpackages
    └── subpackages
```

When I work at the docs, both branches (`dev` and `gh-pages`) get updated, because I change the files in the `docs` directory and then sphinx compiles the html into the `html` directory.

However, when I'm done with the process, I have to manually perform `git add . && git commit` in both the main branch and the `gh-pages` branch, to then push all changes to git.

This is not awfully troublesome, but it would be handy if I could issue one command for all branches. I know that `git push` can be "defaulted" to push all branches (which is what I do) but I found no way of doing this to add and commit such as (for example; just for the sake or clarification)

```
git add . --allbranches
git commit --allbranches -m "updated the docs"
git push
```

or something like that. Is there a way to do it?

Cheers!

Comment: You don’t seem to understand what branches in Git are. Branches do not exist at paths. Please [read a book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: @poke I know I can change branches within one directory and that a branch doesn't have to exist in a specific directory. I use all my 4 branches in my top directory of all my computers, except `gh-pages`, which I leave permanently checked out in the `html` for practical purposes, which is what I meant. Thanks anyway for the book tip.

Comment: you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16389663/4233593) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to commit to multiple branches at one time nor to merge branches not currently checked out.

But you can shorten commands a little bit. To add all changes and make a commit, then push in one line

```
git commit -am "commit message" && git push
```

Answer (score 0):

My projects usually have a top-level directory with "development" stuff. So I would probably make a script `scripts/build_doc.sh` (or whatever language you prefer) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "`git status -z`" != "" ] ; then echo Need clean directory ; exit 1 ; fi

whatever_command_to_rebuild_pages

git add -A dir_to_built_html_pages && \
git commit -m "autobuild" && \
git push
```

Two thoughts: 1) you could do this in a commit-hook, 2) are you sure you want to have generated files in your repository, at all?