# Is it possible to fetch the project's Wiki from the GitHub as a tarball?

Tags: github, wiki

I know that wiki is just another .git repo and that I can clone it, but we are looking for a way to fetch it without having git installed on our server. Is it accessible as a downloadable tarball via some url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to fetch if you clone the wiki into the main repository, say in docs/ or wiki, using a *subtree merge* as explained *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33182223/4058484)*.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of.

I tried a:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/User/project.wiki/tarball/master
wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/User/project.wiki.git/tarball/master
```

Each time, I get a 404.

The [Get Archive API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link) doesn't seem to apply to a wiki repo.