# How to merge two GitHub repos?

Tags: git, github

This question is **not about** how to merge two git repos; that problem has already [been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories) (keywords: "submodules", "subtree merging").

The question here is, how to merge two **GitHub** repos?

I wanted to preserve as many GitHub features/data from both GitHub repos as possible. Most importantly, I want to preserve **issues** and **wikis** from both GitHub repos.

How might I achieve that?

---

Info:

I have just learnt that GitHub wikis [are git repos themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941688/how-to-integrate-a-github-wiki-into-the-main-project) (summary: `git://github.com/you/proj.wiki`), and I have successfully pushed changes to a wiki-repo of mine.

Comment: Github is just a UI for that git repo, with extra sprinkles of good stuff like "issue-tracker" among others. 

The Github website doesn't offer this functionality yet. You'll have to manually do this.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding issues, there is no native way to "import" them, you need to recreate them.

You have for instance a project like "[github-issue-importer](https://github.com/johnf/github-issue-importer)" which could be extended to fetch issues from one GitHub repo and import them in another.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/mkorenkov/1026140) seems to import from one GitHub repo to another.