# Github wiki and tags

Tags: git, github, gollum-wiki

So I have a Github project with a wiki I use to maintain the documentation. Every time something changes in the project or gets added to it, which is bloody often, I document it in the wiki immediately, which helps keep everything documented.

At the same time, most users only get and use periodic binary updates, and therefore need access to the state of the wiki at specific points in time. I know the wiki is a git repository as well, but it is apparently completely separate from the main project repository.

I also know it is possible to integrate the wiki repository as a submodule *(though I can't say I understand how those work, as I don't really have commandline git experience)* but that by itself does not answer my question, which I formulate this way:

**What do I have to do to produce an URL I could just post for the users to direct them to a working wiki, reflecting it's state at the moment of the latest binary release?**

Answer (score 0):

> I also know it is possible to integrate the wiki repository as a submodule (though I can't say I understand how those work, as I don't really have commandline git experience),  but that by itself does not answer my question

It actually could answer the question, since a submodule will record the exact SHA1 of the wiki ([registered as a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6941730/6309))

```
cd /yourRepo
git submodule add -b master https://github.com/you/proj.wiki
git submodule update --init
```

Each time you modify your project, you can:

- go to that submodule,
- modify the wiki, add, commit and push,
- go back to the parent repo, add, commit and push: that will record the SHA1 of the wiki in your parent repo.

When your users get that repo, a simple `git ls-tree master:<path-to-directory-containing-submodule>` can give them the SHA1 of that wiki.
Note that the content of that wiki wouldn't be visible unless those users were to make a:

```
git submodule update --init
```

But if that want only the SHA1, in order to access the wiki at `https://github.com/you/proj.wiki/commit/<SHA1>`, `git ls-tree` is enough (they don't need to populate the submodule with any content).

---

Now, if the submodule approach seems too cumbersome, you could more simply setup a pre-commit hook in your local repo, which would:

- check the SHA1 of the latest commit in your wiki
- put that SHA1 in a file within your local repo (as an url: `https://github.com/you/proj.wiki/commit/<SHA1>`)
- reject the current commit, asking you to add and commit again (since a pre-commit cannot modify the index)

That way, your user would consult that file in order to get the wiki at the right version.

Comment: That would give anyone access to the wiki *files* at a specific point in time, I'm sure -- but if that were all I wanted, I could probably get by with adding a tag to the wiki repository at the time of binary release -- they are based on tags of the master wiki anyway. Would that give them an URL they could just point their browser to and actually browse the snapshot of the wiki, though?

Comment: @RN3AOHthat That is what the second part of my answer is for: registering that URL (`https://github.com/you/proj.wiki/commit/<SHA1>`) in a file, for the users to use.

Comment: @RN3AOH I have edited my answer to make the final url more visible in both solutions

Comment: But will that get the wiki rendered as a working wiki anywhere? Because if it won't, I'm better off compiling the wiki into a PDF or somesuch and including that with the release instead.

Comment: @RN3AOH if that wiki is stored in a git repo accessible by your users, then my answer stands. If not, then yes, including a generated version is possible (avoiding if possible a binary version, like a zip of a pdf, since said version would change often, and would increase the size of the repo)

Comment: That wiki is a Github project wiki... Ok, let me try to formulate it more clearly:

Right now I have https://github.com/username/projectname/wiki, an URL I can give to the users, that renders the content of that builtin repository for the users as a wiki.

Will the method described by you result in an URL that works the same, but refers to the state of a wiki at a previous point in time, or will it just give direct access to raw markdown files at that point in time?

Comment: @RN3AOH then no need to store a generated version: simply store the url of the wiki at the right SHA1 and you are done.

Comment: Um... Are you sure it works that way? If I look at page history, I see sha-links already. However, the links within them that point to other pages of the wiki do not get the same sha applied to them, they point to the latest version -- which makes the wiki not browseable as a wiki. Squishing everything into one page would solve this, but does not at all work for this project.

Comment: @RN3AOH I agree, while the wiki is a git repo, it doesn't seem to benefit from the same "browsable quality and feature" as a regular GitHub repo. That would be a good question for GitHub support.