# Change the github wiki page path

Tags: github, github-pages, wiki

So far I have wrote my github wiki (let's say Toto.wiki) independently from my github Toto project.

I decided that the wiki should be part of my project:
when someone is cloning my project he will also get the wiki.
I have created a docs folder inside my project (Toto/docs) with all the markdown files.

Now I would like to link the github wiki Toto project to the Toto/docs ?
How can I proceed ?  Thanks

Comment: I trust you understand that the public GitHub project's Wiki is allocated its own `<ProjectName>.wiki` repository? Why not use it?

Select the `Wiki` tab and notice the `Clone this wiki locally` - on the right-hand side.

Comment: These Q/As are somewhat related. Perhaps they'll help: 1) [How to store GitHub wiki as part of source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31969868/418950), 2) [How to integrate a GitHub wiki into the main project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941688/418950)

Comment: This article, [GIT-BASED WIKI (GitHub really)](https://www.bit-101.com/blog/2020/09/git-based-wiki/), discusses something like what I believe you are trying to accomplish. See the "System" section and below. Perhaps it offers some ideas you can use.